# print <<< HERE     HERE; Зачем нужна функция.

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Встретилась в коде вот такая функция. Зачем она нужна и какие функции в коде выполняет. Искал в интернете, но ничего не нашел, кроме форумов обсуждения. Кому не трудно опишите простым языком или ссылку на описание. Спасибо.

Comment: Выводит на экран текст

Comment: Ну для чего то конкретного может, прост текст и echo выводит)

Comment: print - выводит строку.

echo - выводит одну и более строк

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это [синтаксис heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Для чего - чтобы не заморачиваться с экранированием, переносами внутри строк и прочее. Для удобства, короче)

Answer (score 0):

Я приведу пример, где можно использовать эту функцию. Ну, например, в PHP коде Вы писали условия if-else, так:

```
if(!isset(переменная)) 
{
и сделай что нибудь;
} 
else        //и хотим, ну например здесь прикрепить HTML форму,тогда пишем!
{
print<<<HERE

  наша форма

HERE;            
}
```

Только осторожно, это функция капризная, следите чтобы после `print<<<HERE` и `HERE;` не было ни одного пробела, а то функция может и не будет работать.

Answer (score 0):

Именно в варианте

```
print <<< HERE HERE;
```

"эта функция" не имеет смысла. Чтобы вывести большой объём текста, надо просто закрыть РНР тег и дальше писать то, что должно быть выведено. Это будет удобнее, проще и понятнее.

Использовать heredoc имеет смысл только если большой кусок текста надо сохранить в переменную.